# Get sku for creating a listing on amazon with sp-api

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Client provided me following requirements for amazon selling partner API.

1. Search product by UPC /Asin.
2. Add Product listing.
   From Which API, I can get sku, as getCatalogItem api does not return any sku?

For product search, I am using following API.
getCatalogItem
https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/catalog/2022-04-01/items?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER&identifiers=025725433841&identifiersType=UPC&includedData=identifiers,summaries,attributes,images,productTypes,salesRanks&locale=en_US

For listing product, I am using PUT /listings/2021-08-01/items/{sellerId}/{sku}.

From Which API, I can get sku, as getCatalogItem api does not return any sku?

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that you will create the SKU value yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.